# Alguna forma de hacer una consulta que contenga tres consulta a la vez? SQL

Tags: php, javascript, sql

Quiero saber si hay alguna manera de que en una sola consulta esta realice tres cosas, hasta donde yo se lo maximo son dos cosas, ya la tercera seria un agente externo, pero igual pregunto por si alguien sabe y me lo pueda compartir, resulta que tengo una tabla current_products todos los datos de esta tabla se envian a otra tabla la cual es finished_products, lo cual la consulta para esto seria:

```
    $query = self::connect()->prepare("INSERT INTO `finished_products` 
    (room, name, lot, quantity_packed, pallet) SELECT room, name, lot, quantity_to_package, finished_pallets 
    FROM `current_products` WHERE `room`=:room");
    $query->execute(["room"=>$room]);
```

una vez que haya insertado esos de datos de la tabla current_products a la finished_products, como pudiera eliminar los datos de la tabla current_products en donde la habitacion sea igual a la habitacion que se le pase, algo asi:

```
        $query = self::connect()->prepare("INSERT INTO `finished_products` 
        (room, name, lot, quantity_packed, pallet) SELECT room, name, lot, quantity_to_package, finished_pallets 
        FROM `current_products` WHERE `room`=:room") DELETE * FROM `current_products` WHERE `room`=:room;
        $query->execute(["room"=>$room]);
```

he pensando en un trigger que se ejecute en la tabla finished_products lo cual haga que elimine los datos de la tabla current_products pero no me sale la sintaxis

gracias :)

**ACTUALIZACION**

hecho con transaccion:

```
$connection = self::connect();
    $connection->beginTransaction();
    
    try {
        $query = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO `finished_products` 
        (room, name, lot, quantity_packed, pallet, start_date, finish_date) SELECT room, name, lot, quantity_to_package, finished_pallets, 
        start_date FROM `current_products` WHERE `room`=:room");
        $query->execute(["room"=>$room]);
        
        $query = $connection->prepare("DELETE FROM `current_products` WHERE `room`=:room");
        $query->execute(["room"=>$room]);
        
        $result = $connection->commit();
    }catch(PDOException $e) {
        $connection->rollBack();
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: Si tu base de datos soporta transacciones, usa una transacción. Este es el caso típico de aplicación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con tu código, cada sentencia SQL que ejecutas lo hace de modo que los resultados se guardan inmediatamente en la base de datos. Primero insertas un registro en `finished_products`. Después borras un registro de `current_products` (la solución alternativa que das, con un *trigger*, es equivalente).

Sin embargo, ¿qué pasa si la primera sentencia falla? Deberías detectar el fallo para no ejecutar la segunda. ¿Y si la primera sentencia no falla pero la segunda sí? Deberías detectar el fallo para deshacer la primera (asegurándote de que se deshace efectivamente); y esperar que no haya pasado nada malo mientras la base de datos ha estado guardando datos incoherentes.

En vez de hacer todo eso, en casos como estos lo más conveniente es ejecutar las sentencias como una sola transacción. El ejemplo típico de transacción es una transferencia de fondos entre dos cuentas bancarias. Sería un desastre que se añadieran fondos en la cuenta destino sin retirarlos de la cuenta origen. La operación, desde el punto de vista lógico, es "transferir", no "añadir" y "retirar". Si la operación no se puede ejecutar como "transferir", no se debe realizar. Y para eso se ejecuta como una transacción:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE `accounts` SET `balance` = `balance` + 101.63 WHERE `id` = 1422;
UPDATE `accounts` SET `balance` = `balance` - 101.63 WHERE `id` = 6877;
COMMIT
```

Una vez iniciada la transacción, las sentencias se ejecutan pero los cambios no se guardarán hasta que hagas un `COMMIT`. Si alguna sentencia da error, todos los cambios se desharán hasta el inicio de la transacción. Además, entre `BEGIN TRANSACTION` y `COMMIT` puedes ejecutar un `ROLLBACK` en cualquier momento para dejar todo como estaba al iniciarse la transacción.

Esta es la solución natural a tu problema, suponiendo que tu motor de base de datos soporte transacciones. Por ejemplo MySQL (con InnoDB) y PostgreSQL soportan transacciones (MySQL con MyISAM no).

Comment: muy bueno, no habia pensando en eso de que pudiera fallar el primero o el segundo, de todos modos lo hice con transacciones como me dijieron arriba, te muestro el codigo para ver si esta aceptable o bien implementado, actualizo la pregunta, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Al montar el `prepare` este te pide un `string` que contenga la sentencia SQL. Este `string` puede contener más de una sentencia, separadas por punto y coma.

```
    $query = self::connect()->prepare("INSERT INTO `finished_products` 
    (room, name, lot, quantity_packed, pallet) SELECT room, name, lot, quantity_to_package, finished_pallets 
    FROM `current_products` WHERE `room`=:room;DELETE * FROM `current_products` WHERE `room`=:room;");
    $query->execute(["room"=>$room]);
```

Comment: amigo lo tengo asi:

$query = self::connect()->prepare("INSERT INTO `finished_products` 
        (room, name, lot, quantity_packed, pallet) SELECT room, name, lot, quantity_to_package, finished_pallets 
        FROM `current_products` WHERE `room`=:room", "DELETE * FROM `current_products` WHERE `room`=:room");
        $query->execute(["room"=>$room]);

pero me sale el error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean

Comment: Por eso no te funciona, prueba con la que he puesto, fíjate en lo que hay antes del `DELETE` y en la explicación que te he dado.

Comment: si, ya vi, pero no hace nada, lo tengo asi: 

$query = self::connect()->prepare("INSERT INTO `finished_products` 
        (room, name, lot, quantity_packed, pallet) SELECT room, name, lot, quantity_to_package, finished_pallets 
        FROM `current_products` WHERE `room`=:room ; DELETE * FROM `current_products` WHERE `room`=:room");
        return $query->execute(["room"=>$room]);

Comment: Despues del último `WHERE room=:room");` debe ser `WHERE room=:room;");` Es decir con un punto y coma después de `:room`

Comment: nop,  $query = self::connect()->prepare("INSERT INTO `finished_products` 
        (room, name, lot, quantity_packed, pallet) SELECT room, name, lot, quantity_to_package, finished_pallets 
        FROM `current_products` WHERE `room`=:room ; DELETE * FROM `current_products` WHERE `room`=:room;");
        return $query->execute(["room"=>$room]);